# I want to create an apllication using nexjs for UI, Node express for API also I want to implement Auth0

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, next.js, auth0

Implementing Auth0 for NEXT js client and Node express server

When I implemented auth0 with node it returns a UI for Login/SignUp by Auth0 how can I show it in my nextjs client. Is there any package in next to solve this issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.